# Picking a Partition in installer

Tags: installation, mac, partitioning

I was installing Ubuntu and I had no idea which partition was the one I created for Linux. I called it Linux and its a "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". I think thats what it's supposed to be but I can't tell which partition it is. Is there a way to tell or to make a show a name? [Here's](http://addisonbean.com/ubuntu1.jpg) a link to a picture of what is shows.
And I gave it 20 GB and none of those say 20GB. I'm on a mac with OS X 10.8.2 if that helps.

Or can I just delete my Linux partition and make it in the installer?

Comment: Your first mistake was that you didn’t use GParted for creating the partition :) It’s available on Ubuntu try.

Comment: Well I can't use that because I don't have Ubuntu yet

Comment: Oh wait do mean the thing that says try Ubuntu? Ok I'll try it thanks :)

Comment: Yes :D and you could make screenshots just by pressing Print key on the keyboard, if you would choose to try!

Comment: So should I delete the partition I already for ubuntu made before using gparted or should I just keep it?

Comment: No no, in the installation process, choose “Try something else” in Installation Type. Then *carefully* select the partition and click on change/edit (I can’t remember). Then select **ex4** for the type, check the box for **format**, and set **/** as mount point. It’s done!

Comment: Thanks! I did all that but I don't know what to pick as my boot loader installation device. I tried /dev/sda4 and it said I should get a seperate partition. Does that mean I need to make a new one or can use /dev/sda4

Comment: No, you shouldn't change that :) It must be your hard drive, **/dev/sda** as I see in your picture. Don’t worry, it doesn’t make any changes in your other partitions.

Comment: Well I installed it and started it up and it froze...

Comment: Sorry! I have no idea about this! Search here in askubuntu. Check more times to see if it's frequent.

Answer (score 2):

From the image you posted I would say is the **sda4** of 19.3GB.

Comment: Ok so if I choose that will it not ruin any of my stuff on my main partition? I'm really scared haha

Comment: @addison no, you just need to format it to Ex4 or another *ex* type.

Comment: as AliNa says i would format sda4 to an ext4. If you are scared backup your files to an external drive!